# Windows vs linux http authentication. javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, http-get, httpconnection

When trying to make a http connection on my windows machine I get the following exception on                        httpclient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticate
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
```

I think i need to add some certificates to java or the browser on the windows machine, but where do I get them from? Why does it work fine on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog might help: http://javaskeleton.blogspot.com/2010/07/avoiding-peer-not-authenticated-with.html